# Adding A table to the entity without using Scaffold DbContext

Tags: c#, entity-framework, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I am using .Net Core with Entity framework 'Scaffold-DbContext'.
I need to add a new table to database without updating the ApplicationDbContext using scaffold command . 
So I did the following steps :

1. Create the class with the relation
2. use model builder in ApplicationDbContext (to generate the fields)
3. add the virtual DbSet

i rebuild my code , everything works fine !
but when i use it it gives :'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Invalid object name '.

any help would be thankful . 
here is my codes :

----Part One

```
public class PatientDoctor
{
    public int PatientDoctorId { get; set; }
    public int ?DoctorId { get; set; }
    public int ?PatientId { get; set; }

    public Patient Patient { get; set; }
    public Doctor Doctor { get; set; }
}
```

----Part Two

```
modelBuilder.Entity<PatientDoctor>(entity => {
            entity.HasKey(e => e.PatientDoctorId);

            entity.HasOne(e => e.Doctor).
            WithMany(p => p.PatientDoctors).
            HasForeignKey(d => d.DoctorId).
            HasConstraintName("FK_PatientDoctor_Doctor");

            entity.HasOne(e => e.Patient).
            WithMany(p => p.PatientDoctors).
            HasForeignKey(e => e.PatientId).
            HasConstraintName("FK_PatientDoctor_Patient");
        });
```

---Part Three : 
     `public virtual DbSet<PatientDoctor> PatientDoctors { get; set; }`

Comment: Did you also execute "add migrations" and "database update" in your CLI ?

Comment: no i did not , it 's not code first approach . Should i? , i have created the table in database with the same exact fields naming

Comment: Does your database and your tables already exists ?

Comment: @Skrface yes sure

Comment: So if I understand you well, you already have an existing database and you want to add a new table in it. If this table doesn't exists yet, you should use migrations to update the database from your code. Is it what you are looking for ? If it is, I can give you an answer on how to do it with an existing database.

Comment: @Skrface the table already exist

Comment: Is your application already able to read/write data in the database, or is it the first table you try to work with in your application ?

Comment: @Skrface   no , it has all  access, it is not the first table

Comment: If your connection string is correct and if you are able to work with the database from your app, it means you have a misconfiguration between your table definition and its code definition. Without seeing more code and without the table definiton, it is going to be hard to sort it out.

Comment: @Skrface i found the answer . In the DbSet<PatientDoctor> PatientDoctors 
i made it singular PatientDoctor and it works . i have no idea why is that but it works

Comment: Right, just a tiny misconfiguration then. Glad you sorted it out !

Comment: @Skrface thank you my friend . best regards

Answer (score 0):

I have only changed :

```
public virtual DbSet<PatientDoctor> PatientDoctors { get; set; }
```

To :

```
public virtual DbSet<PatientDoctor> PatientDoctor { get; set; }
```

It seams a small bug in entity framework

Comment: not a bug, by design... there is a config/convention to allow plural tables